# Python openpyxl using sheet.row_dimensions[2].fill with an unexpected result

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl  to do some Excel exercrise and i want to fill the color to one of the row.

but finally i found the color not fill on my text but on the blank row,what happen to it???

Here's my codes:

```
import  openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

excel=openpyxl.load_workbook('12_6_produceSales.xlsx')
sheet=excel.active
fillcolor=PatternFill(fill_type='solid',start_color='668B8B')
sheet.row_dimensions[2].fill=fillcolor
excel.save('12_6.xlsx')
```

And here's the result it fill the color only on the blank row, in fact i want to fill the whole row 1
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, this will dynamically work and no need to specify cell names.
mark it as solved......

```
import  openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

excel=openpyxl.load_workbook('12_6_produceSales.xlsx')
sheet=excel.active
fillcolor=PatternFill(fill_type='solid',start_color='668B8B')

for cell in sheet["1:1"]:
    cell.fill = fillcolor

excel.save('12_6.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing colour for cells,[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSzVL.png)

```
import  openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
excel=openpyxl.load_workbook('12_6_produceSales.xlsx')
sheet=excel.active
fillcolor=PatternFill(fill_type='solid',start_color='668B8B')

sheet['A1'].fill = fillcolor
sheet['B1'].fill = fillcolor
sheet['C1'].fill = fillcolor
sheet['D1'].fill = fillcolor

excel.save('12_6.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering, is there any other way to easily do this? in this case there's only 5 rows ,and i have another case it almost have 20k rows, so manually fill color is really a tough task

Comment: i have added code in one more https://stackoverflow.com/a/62424772/10849457 answer @M_Sea